# Sorting 2d point array to find out four corners

Tags: sorting, opencv

Hi I have the collection of 2d points which can be of any size .By finding min and max value of the distance between origin I am able to find out the top left and bottom-right corner point but I am not able to find out top-right and bottom left point.

Comment: use `boundingRect` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect and compute the top right and bottom left according to the shortest distance to the bounding rect corners. Though I think your method (even for top left and bottom right points) might fail for some simple examples and so my way would fail in the same way ;) .

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use `cv::approxPoly()` to find the corners of your set of 2D points. Then you can sort the points in any order you want in the following way:

```
//Sorts a vector of 4 points into top left, top right, bottomleft, bottomright
vector<Point> sortPoints(vector<Point> unsorted) {
    vector<Point> sorted;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)sorted.push_back(Point(0, 0));
    int middleX = (unsorted[0].x + unsorted[1].x + unsorted[2].x + unsorted[3].x) / 4;
    int middleY = (unsorted[0].y + unsorted[1].y + unsorted[2].y + unsorted[3].y) / 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) {
        if (unsorted.at(i).x < middleX && unsorted.at(i).y < middleY)sorted[0] = unsorted.at(i);
        if (unsorted.at(i).x > middleX && unsorted.at(i).y < middleY)sorted[1] = unsorted.at(i);
        if (unsorted.at(i).x < middleX && unsorted.at(i).y > middleY)sorted[2] = unsorted.at(i);
        if (unsorted.at(i).x > middleX && unsorted.at(i).y > middleY)sorted[3] = unsorted.at(i);
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

`p1(left,top), p2(right,bottom)`.

Now get values top,left, bottom and right and form other points:

`p3(right,top), p4(left,bottom)`.