# Fine Tuning Hough Line function parameters OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I've been trying to get 4 lines around the square so that I can obtain the vertices of the square. I'm going with this approach rather than finding corners directly using Harris or contours method due to accuracy. Using houghlines in built function in opencv I'm unable to get full length lines to get intersection points and I'm also getting too many irrelevant lines. I'd like to know if the parameters can be fine tuned to obtain my requirements? If yes how do I go about it? My question is exactly the same as this one [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303396/choosing-lines-from-hough-lines) However I'm not getting those lines itself even after changing those parameters. I've attached the original image along with the code and output:

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{

    Mat image,src;
    image = imread("c:/pics/output2_1.bmp");
    src = image.clone();
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(image, image, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU + CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    namedWindow("thresh", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow("thresh", 600, 400);

    imshow("thresh", image);

    cv::Mat edges;

    cv::Canny(image, edges, 0, 255);

    vector<Vec2f> lines;
    HoughLines(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 100, 0, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a));
        line(src, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

namedWindow("Edges Structure", WINDOW_NORMAL);
resizeWindow("Edges Structure", 600, 400);

imshow("Edges Structure", src);
waitKey(0);

return(0);
}
```

Output Image:

[image: HoughLinesOutput]

Update: There is a frame on this image, so I was able to reduce the irrelevant lines in the border of the image by removing that frame, however I'm still not getting complete lines covering the square.

Comment: Just extrapolate lines near each other and average them to produce a line for each side. Then use slope intercept form `y=mx+b` to get an equation for each line, and you can find the intersection points mathematically. Alternatively, it's a little slower but you can use `HoughLines` instead of `HoughLinesP` to get lines the full distance of the image, which will be easier to  a average, but you'll still need to convert to slope intercept form from rho,theta form.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds By doing that I'm missing out on accuracy, I need those lines perfectly touching the complete edge of the square.

Comment: In fact, by doing that, you would be increasing the accuracy. You would be able to set the threshold higher for the Hough transform since you would be extrapolating the line through the length of the image. Your lines are currently much more inaccurate now than they would be averaged.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Could you please provide me a code sample of how to go about it ?

Comment: Since you have such a well-defined boundary, you don't even need to average multiple lines, you can threshold so that you get one line per side with `HoughLines` instead of `HoughLinesP`. An easy way to get better lines is to `cv2.dilate` your edge map so that the edges grow a little bit, so that lines can get more votes. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: My original suggestion isn't great for your image when you're using `HoughLinesP` because some lines can be vertical or nearly vertical, so you may not be able to calculate the slope. Instead, see my final answer...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are *many* ways to do this, I will give an example of just one. However, I'm quickest in `python`, so my code example will be in that language. Should not be hard to translate it, though (please feel free to edit your post with your C++ solution after you've finished it for others).

For preprocessing, I highly suggest [`dilate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=cv2.dilate#dilate)ing your edge image. This will make the lines *thicker* which will help fit the Hough lines better. What the Hough lines function does in the abstract is basically make a grid of lines passing through a ton of angles and distances, and if the lines go over any white pixels from Canny, then it gives that line a score for each point it goes through. However, the lines from Canny won't be perfectly straight, so you'll get a few different lines scoring. Making those Canny lines thicker will mean each line that is *really* close to fitting well will have better chances of scoring higher.

[image: Dilated Canny]

If you're going to use `HoughLinesP`, then your output will be line *segments*, where all you have is two points on the line.

Since the lines are mostly vertical and horizontal, you can easily split the lines based on their position. If the two *y*-coordinates of one line are near each other, then the line is mostly horizontal. If the two *x*-coordinates are near each other, then the line is mostly vertical. So you can segment your lines into vertical lines and horizontal lines that way.

```
def segment_lines(lines, delta):
    h_lines = []
    v_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            if abs(x2-x1) < delta: # x-values are near; line is vertical
                v_lines.append(line)
            elif abs(y2-y1) < delta: # y-values are near; line is horizontal
                h_lines.append(line)
    return h_lines, v_lines
```

[image: Segmented Hough lines]

Then, you can obtain intersection points of two line segments from their endpoints [using determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line).

```
def find_intersection(line1, line2):
    # extract points
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line1[0]
    x3, y3, x4, y4 = line2[0]
    # compute determinant
    Px = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    Py = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    return Px, Py
```

So now if you loop through all your lines, you'll have intersection points from all your horizontal and vertical lines, but you have *many* lines, so you'll have many intersection points for the same corner of the box.

[image: Intersections]

However, these are all in one vector, so not only do you need to average the points in each corner, you need to actually group them together, too. You can achieve this with *k*-means clustering, which is implemented in OpenCV as [`kmeans()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/clustering.html?highlight=kmeans#kmeans).

```
def cluster_points(points, nclusters):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    _, _, centers = cv2.kmeans(points, nclusters, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
    return centers
```

Finally, we can simply plot those centers (making sure we round first---since so far everything is a float) onto the image with [`circle()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=circle#circle) to make sure we've done it right.

[image: k-means clustered corner points]

And we have it; four points, at the corners of the box.

Here's my full code in python, including the code to generate the figures above:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

def find_intersection(line1, line2):
    # extract points
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line1[0]
    x3, y3, x4, y4 = line2[0]
    # compute determinant
    Px = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    Py = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4))/  \
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    return Px, Py

def segment_lines(lines, delta):
    h_lines = []
    v_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            if abs(x2-x1) < delta: # x-values are near; line is vertical
                v_lines.append(line)
            elif abs(y2-y1) < delta: # y-values are near; line is horizontal
                h_lines.append(line)
    return h_lines, v_lines

def cluster_points(points, nclusters):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    _, _, centers = cv2.kmeans(points, nclusters, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS)
    return centers

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# preprocessing
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=.5, fy=.5)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
dilated = cv2.dilate(edges, np.ones((3,3), dtype=np.uint8))

cv2.imshow("Dilated", dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('dilated.png', dilated)

# run the Hough transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilated, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, maxLineGap=20, minLineLength=50)

# segment the lines
delta = 10
h_lines, v_lines = segment_lines(lines, delta)

# draw the segmented lines
houghimg = img.copy()
for line in h_lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        color = [0,0,255] # color hoz lines red
        cv2.line(houghimg, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color=color, thickness=1)
for line in v_lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        color = [255,0,0] # color vert lines blue
        cv2.line(houghimg, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color=color, thickness=1)

cv2.imshow("Segmented Hough Lines", houghimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('hough.png', houghimg)

# find the line intersection points
Px = []
Py = []
for h_line in h_lines:
    for v_line in v_lines:
        px, py = find_intersection(h_line, v_line)
        Px.append(px)
        Py.append(py)

# draw the intersection points
intersectsimg = img.copy()
for cx, cy in zip(Px, Py):
    cx = np.round(cx).astype(int)
    cy = np.round(cy).astype(int)
    color = np.random.randint(0,255,3).tolist() # random colors
    cv2.circle(intersectsimg, (cx, cy), radius=2, color=color, thickness=-1) # -1: filled circle

cv2.imshow("Intersections", intersectsimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('intersections.png', intersectsimg)

# use clustering to find the centers of the data clusters
P = np.float32(np.column_stack((Px, Py)))
nclusters = 4
centers = cluster_points(P, nclusters)
print(centers)

# draw the center of the clusters
for cx, cy in centers:
    cx = np.round(cx).astype(int)
    cy = np.round(cy).astype(int)
    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), radius=4, color=[0,0,255], thickness=-1) # -1: filled circle

cv2.imshow("Center of intersection clusters", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('corners.png', img)
```

---

Finally, just one question...why not use the [Harris corner detector](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) implemented in OpenCV as [`cornerHarris()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cv2.cornerharris#cornerharris)? Because it works really well with very minimal code. I thresholded the grayscale image, and then gave a little blur to remove spurious corners, and, well...

[image: Harris corner detector]

This was produced with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

# preprocessing
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=.5, fy=.5)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
r, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 3)

# run harris
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

# dilate the corner points for marking
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# threshold
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('harris.png', img)
```

I think with some minor adjustments the Harris corner detector can probably be much more accurate than extrapolating Hough line intersections.

Comment: Harris is very random. I need to choose right parameters for it to return 4 consistent points. The reason I'm not keen on using Harris is because there are other shapes that I need to detect vertices for, so it doesn't work all the time. I'm trying to measure the lengths in micrometer so I need high accuracy and precision.

Comment: And in your function def segment_lines(lines, delta): , what is delta?

Comment: The variable `delta` is simply how far away I'm letting `x` or `y` differ before saying they're not on the same line. I used `delta=10` for my example. This segmentation assumes your lines are nearly horizontal or vertical though. If your lines can be angled, then you would want to use the slope. But if your lines can be almost vertical, you have to worry about an exploding or nonexistent slope, in that case, you would want to use the `rho, theta` form like the Hough transform uses.

Comment: Also I understand the need for accuracy, but my point was that Hough is *not at all* accurate. It is one huge approximation step, especially using `HoughLinesP`. And it's also important to define what an accurate corner *is*. Is it the pixel inside the box, or outside the box? If the pixel at the corner is more gray, between black and white, is that the corner or are the black or white pixels beside that the corner? You might have better luck finding a good method if you post a new question with what you *actually need* and expectations of it.

Comment: what could be the reason for not getting any corner points after clustering ? I am trying to implement your code.. it gives many circles but after clustering it returns None and am applying it on the perspective projection of rectangle.

Comment: @Eyshika I'm not sure without seeing your code, tbh it sounds impossible as I think OpenCV should always return some centers (whether or not they are accurate is a different matter). Feel free to open up a new question and link me to it.