# Getting a quadrangle of a scanned ID card in OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am looking for a solution to identify a quadrangle of a scanned ID card in OpenCV-Python, as given in the image below. Any solution/suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486078/opencv-how-to-find-rectangle-contour-of-a-rectangle-with-round-corner

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555629/algorithm-to-detect-corners-of-paper-sheet-in-photo). So I would recommend you read that thread.

I would recommend reading that first and then attempting to solve the problem. If you have more specific questions then I would post those to StackOverflow after you try to figure them out yourself. As your question stands currently I believe it isn't a good fit for this site as it is far too broad and doesn't show any research or attempt to address the issue yourself, but good luck!

Comment: No problem, sorry to be a bit harsh but I hope that the question I linked is helpful to you.

Comment: No prob. You are right. I just need to do a bit of homework/research first.